# Is Vergara correct about the nature of the Devil?

Tags: thirty-coins

In the second season of *30 Monedas* (*30 Coins*), Vergara states that God and the Devil are the same entity, with God taking on the Devil persona to accomplish certain things that would be distasteful otherwise.

However, there is some reason to question the veracity of these statements: to start with, the only source of information that Vergara has for this is a literal demon, Father Ángel; Father Ángel has at different times been referred both as the Devil and as working for the Devil; and perhaps most notably, Ángel, whose goals should be those of the Devil, has Vergara working to *stop* Barbrow, whose goal is to bring God to Earth and thus destroy the world.

Within the context of the series, is Vergara correct?